# Some Modification Required for Social Engine Software

Tags: socialengine

I'm Using Trail of Social Engine 4, i installed on localhost xampp

Here is the question Social engine Directory is like this www.mywebsite.com/members/username

But I required like this
www.mywebsite.com/username    how to remove this **members** from url please help me out

Answer (score 1):

For this you have to make changes in defined routes at file path: "application/modules/User/settings/manifest.php". But change in routes also can affect other urls.

Comment: you have to modify this line 
    'route' => 'members/:controller/:action/*',

Answer (score 0):

At the current time its not possible to do this with socialEngine, our routing depends on `members` being present.